# Proper way to use two contexts in asp.net core with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to apply what I have been studying and I have been involved in a part of contexts.

What I'm trying to apply is a Microsoft.Identity structure along with the application entities.

Structure of the solution:

```
BaseFull.Web
BaseFull.Entities
BaseFull.Infra.Data
```

I have created an interface to keep the same new properties and so do not have problem of migration of two classes to the same 'table'

```
public interface IUsuario
{
    string Fullname { get; set; }
}
```

I applied to my User entity and ApplicationUser:

```
namespace BaseFull.Web.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser,  IUsuario
    {
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace BaseFull.Entities.Models
{
    public class Usuario : IUsuario
    {
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public Usuario()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        #region Propriedades da AspnetUsers(Identity)
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual string UserName { get; set; }


  ...
        #endregion
    }
```

I've separated the entities in a project. I am also trying to separate the context in a project and it is at this moment that I am in difficulties.

```
 namespace BaseFull.Infra.Data.Context
{
    public class BaseFullContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
....

namespace BaseFull.Web.Data
{
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Usuarios");
```

In the Startup class of the Web project I made the call of the contexts:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDbContext<BaseFullContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));....
```

I had an assembly error, which I resolved by changing the service to the same assembly as the main project

```
services.AddDbContext<BaseFullAppContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
                                , b => b.MigrationsAssembly("BaseFull.Web"))
```

However, running the second context update generated the error 'table already exists'.

```
There is already an object named 'Usuarios' in the database.
```

My biggest question is how to solve this problem, which is the most correct and efficient way to use both contexts for this.

The User configuration class to remain the same as ApplicationUser did not show here because I do not think it's necessary, but if I need to, I'll show it as well.

Comment: What use case would call for separating your tables into two contexts?  This would make writing queries between both contexts difficult. It would require joins from both contexts to be done in application memory instead of the sql server.  My recommendation is to put all your tables into the `ApplicationDbContext`.  I can show you how to do this if you want, just let me know.

Comment: Totally agree with @DavidLee You shouldn't have two contexts sharing the same connection string. If they were different connection strings (connecting to two different databases, for example), then it would make more sense. But you can't have any relationships between the two, not even inheritance.

Comment: You would use something like that when working with bounded contexts, but from the OP example I don't see how that's applicable. It's almost like they saw 2 different examples of context setup and have set 2 up, one each way?? To the original question: To have a table appear in both contexts then only one context can serve as the owner of the table structure with CodeFirst. Every other context must be configured to *not* create/migrate schema. For bounded contexts I do not use CodeFirst, but even then only 1 context can be the owner of any given entity.

Comment: Agree with the above; One thing I fail to understand based on what you have shown is 

Why would you need 2 Context, what are you trying to achieve? You either use 2 context for 2 separate databases or an identity database and extend it